# Benchmark de chamadas usando HttpFactory

Tags: c#, injeção-de-dependência, benchmark

Estou utilizando a biblioteca BenchmarkDotNet com a intenção de comparar as chamadas feitas via HttpClient vs IHttpClientFactory.

Sei que não é possível colocar parâmetros no construtor ou em um método de setup para realizar o benchmark, portanto, gostaria de saber se existe outra forma de chamar essa classe IHttpClientFactory para conseguir fazer os testes. Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Com ajuda de colegas, achei a solução:

```
    private IHttpClientFactory? _factory;
    private HttpClient? _httpClientFactory;

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void GlobalSetup()
    {
        _httpClientFactory = new();

        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddHttpClient()
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        _factory = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();
        _httpClientFactory = _factory.CreateClient();
    }
```

Basta agora utilizar a variável privada *_httpClientFactory* para realizar as chamadas HTTP.